# How to overclock my monitor past the stock 1080p75 without the setting getting changed to 1080p59?

Tags: display, overclocking

How to overclock my monitor used for my laptop past 1080p75.

I was going to overclock to 1080p80 from 1080p75, but when I change the settings and click apply, the screen flashes and returns to 1080p59.

My HDMI Cable is not a problem and the monitor is not overclocked from the factory.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it is possible to increase the refresh rate of ***some*** LCD monitors past their documented settings.  However, doing so - or even ***attempting*** to - can damage or destroy your monitor.

Additionally, going from 75 Hz to 80 Hz will not likely produce enough of a change to be noticeable by the human eye.  Is the extreme risk worth such little reward?  That is up to you.

There are three methods of "overclocking" a monitor:

1. Lowering your resolution - Technically not overclocking, but some monitors support higher refresh rates at lower resolutions
2. GPU settings - Software provided by your GPU allows for the creation and use of custom resolutions and refresh rates
3. 3rd party software - Same as #2, but from a third party

Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jUwwtNIRndo) that briefly goes through these options.

In my opinion, such small benefits are not worth the risks.

Comment: Unsupported modes have long since been rejected by displays. I don’t see any real risk here. Of course, there’s no benefit either.